# Overlay multiple lines from data frame with index column onto existing plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, (Id, Lat, Long), you can construct a small section of this with the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Id=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  Lat=c(58.12550, 58.17426, 58.46461, 58.45812, 58.45207, 58.44512, 58.43358, 58.42727, 57.77700, 57.76034, 57.73614, 57.72411, 57.70498, 57.68453),
  Long=c(-5.098068, -5.314452, -4.914108, -4.899922, -4.887067, -4.873312, -4.852384, -4.840817, -5.666568, -5.648711, -5.617588, -5.594681, -5.557740, -5.509405))
```

The `Id` column is an index column. So all the rows with the same `Id` number have the coordinates for a single line. In my data frame this `Id` number varies from 1 through to 7696. So I have 7696 lines to plot.

Each `Id` number relates to an individual separate line of `Lat` and `Long` coordinates. What I want to do is overlay onto an existing plot all of these 7696 individual lines.

With the example data above this contains the `Lat` & `Long` coordinates for lines 1, 2, 3.

What is the best way to overlay all these lines onto an existing plot, I was thinking maybe some kind of loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  Id=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  Lat=c(58.12550, 58.17426, 58.46461, 58.45812, 58.45207, 58.44512, 58.43358, 58.42727, 57.77700, 57.76034, 57.73614, 57.72411, 57.70498, 57.68453),
  Long=c(-5.098068, -5.314452, -4.914108, -4.899922, -4.887067, -4.873312, -4.852384, -4.840817, -5.666568, -5.648711, -5.617588, -5.594681, -5.557740, -5.509405))


library(ggplot2)
#plot
ggplot(data=df,aes(Lat,Long,colour=as.factor(Id))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Using base R:

```
#plot blank
with(df,plot(Lat,Long,type="n"))
#plot lines
for(i in unique(df$Id))
  with(df[ df$Id==i,],lines(Lat,Long,col=i))
```

[image]

Comment: That is great, however I want this to overlay the lines over an existing plot, not on a new plot. Any ideas?

Comment: Using base R solution, just use `lines`, it plots on existing. It would help if you clarify how the existing plot was generated.

Comment: I had not seen the base R suggestion. That works great. The lines are geological faults, and the base map is a map of the UK via the maps package. I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think that any approach to take is going to result in a *very* cluttered plot since you have so many `Id`s (unless their lines do not overlap much). Either way, I would probably use `ggplot2` for this.

```
##
if( !("ggplot2" %in% installed.packages()[,1]) ){
    install.packages("ggplot2",dependencies=TRUE)
}
library(ggplot2)
##
D <- data.frame(
    Id=Id,
    Lat=Lat,
    Long=Long
)
##
ggplot(data=D,aes(x=Lat,y=Long,group=Id,color=Id))+
    geom_point()+ ## you might want to omit geom_point() in your plot
    geom_line()
##
```

The reason I used `group=Id, color=Id` in `aes()` rather than passing `Id` as a factor to `aes()` and just using `color=Id` is that you will end up with a legend containing 7000+ factor levels (the majority of which will not be visible in the plot area).

Comment: That is great, however I want this to overlay the lines over an existing plot, not on a new plot. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking - do you mean you already have a plot made with the base R function `plot()` and you want to overlay the data on that? Or are you fine with using a `ggplot()` as long as it can be updated dynamically? For instance, if you run my previous code, you can make use of the `last_plot()` command in `ggplot2`:
`D2 <- data.frame(Id=rep(4,2),Lat=D$Lat[1:2]*1.05,Long=D$Long[1:2]*1.2);`
 
`last_plot()+geom_line(data=D2,aes(x=Lat,y=Long,color=Id,group=Id))`

Comment: Thanks for the above, my existing plot is from the maps package and the lines are geological faults which I just wanted to overlay. I shall try your solution later today. Thanks for your help.